# How to implement an iterator for a two leveled map in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Consider we have a map `std::map<Level1Key, std::map<Level2Key, T>>`, and we will consider some operations on `T` here.

We will have `using TwoLevelMap = std::map<Level1Key, std::map<Level2Key, T>>;` here, for simplicity.

Also, this is a simplified version of my real problem, in which I can't use `(level1, level2)` as key. So we will only discuss in the "two-level" map context.

---

The first case is `find`. If we can't find `(level1, level2)`, we have some output something like `map.end()`. However, I really understand that we can't have an universal representation like `std::string::npos` here, so there comes the first trouble.

Should I use `std::map<Level2Key, T>::end()`? However, it is not plausible, because we don't know which `end` it should compare to. For example, it have to be like the following, which is quite ugly, since we have to access `m.at(level1key)` first! Such operation will throw!

```
if (m.find(level1key, level2key) == m.at(level1key).end()) {
}
```

---

The second case is `erase` by an iterator. Consider the following case, hoe can we implement `magicErase`, if we only knows `level2_iter`?

```
m.magicErase(level2_iter);
```

So we can only do this, which always requires to search the map(costy).

```
m.magicErase(level1_key, level2_key);
```

To my intuition, could there be something like `TwoLevelIter` for this?

```
struct TwoLevelIter {
    Level1Iter iter1;
    Level2Iter iter2;
};
```

Then we have to write a special magicErase like

```
void magicErase() {
    iter->level1.erase(iter->level2);
}
```

---

So, I want to know what is the best practice to solve my problem here?

Comment: `std::optional<std::pair<level1key, level2key>>` is a way to solve this problem. The empty option serves as the end iterator. You need something like that anyway to represent the end of an empty first-level map (there is no second-level map to get an iterator from), to compute `next`, to implement `equal_range`...

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Yes, I actually did this. However, it does not solve my next question, because when I want to delete something, there will be an extra search.

Comment: Not sure I follow, where is the extra search if you have both level iterators?

Comment: OK, maybe I misinterpret something, is `level1key` here a key or an iterator?

Comment: ah sorry, I mean iterator, not key. My bad. `std::optional<std::pair<level1iter, level2iter>>`.

Comment: OK, that actually solves most of my question. However, like you have said, this is not actually an iterator, because it doesn't implement most trait of an iterator?

Comment: You can make it into a full fledged iterator but you need to implement most of the traits yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap your nested map up into a class with a custom iterator. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

template <typename Level1Key, typename Level2Key, typename T>
class TwoLevelMap
{
public:
  using Level2Map = std::map<Level2Key, T>;
  using Level1Map = std::map<Level1Key, Level2Map>;

  class iterator
  {
  public:
    Level1Map* map = nullptr;
    typename Level1Map::iterator first;
    typename Level2Map::iterator second;
    using value_type = std::pair<Level1Key, std::pair<Level2Key, T>>;

    auto operator<=>(const iterator&) const = default;

    iterator& operator++()
    {
      second++;
      if (second == first->second.end())
      {
        first++;
        if (first == map->end())
        {
          second = {};
        }
        else
        {
          second = first->second.begin();
        }
      }
      return *this;
    }

    iterator operator++(int)
    {
      iterator old = *this;
      operator++();
      return old;
    }

    iterator& operator--()
    {
      if (first == map->end() || second == first->second.begin())
      {
        if (first == map->begin())
        {
          throw std::logic_error("invalid iterator");
        }
        first--;
        second = first->second.end();
      }
      second--;
      return *this;
    }

    iterator operator--(int)
    {
      iterator old = *this;
      operator--();
      return old;
    }

    value_type operator*()
    {
      return { first->first, { second->first, second->second } };
    }
  };

  iterator insert_or_assign(const Level1Key& level1, const Level2Key& level2, const T& value)
  {
    auto it = map.find(level1);
    if (it == map.end())
    {
      it = map.insert({ level1, {{level2, value}} }).first;
      return { &map,  it, it->second.begin() };
    }
    else
    {
      return { &map,  it, it->second.insert_or_assign(level2, value).first };
    }
  }

  iterator find(const Level1Key& level1, const Level2Key& level2)
  {
    auto first = map.find(level1);
    if (first == map.end())
    {
      return end();
    }
    auto second = first->second.find(level2);
    if (second == first->second.end())
    {
      return end();
    }
    return { &map, first, second };
  }

  iterator erase(iterator pos)
  {
    auto second = pos.first->second.erase(pos.second);
    if (pos.first->second.empty())
    {
      auto first = map.erase(pos.first);
      return { &map, first, first == map.end() ? typename Level2Map::iterator() : first->second.begin() };
    }
    else
    {
      return { &map, pos.first, second };
    }
  }

  iterator begin()
  {
    return { &map, map.begin(), {map.empty() ? typename Level2Map::iterator() : map.begin()->second.begin() } };
  }

  iterator end()
  {
    return { &map, map.end(), typename Level2Map::iterator() };
  }

private:
  Level1Map map;
};

int main() {
  TwoLevelMap<std::string, std::string, int> map;
  map.insert_or_assign("a", "b", 1);
  map.insert_or_assign("a", "c", 2);
  map.insert_or_assign("a", "d", 3);
  map.insert_or_assign("b", "a", 4);
  std::cout << "forward\n";
  for (auto value : map)
  {
    std::cout << value.first << ", " << value.second.first << ", " << value.second.second << "\n";
  }
  std::cout << "reverse\n";
  for (auto it = --map.end(); it != map.begin(); it--)
  {
    auto value = *it;
    std::cout << value.first << ", " << value.second.first << ", " << value.second.second << "\n";
  }
  std::cout << "find\n";
  auto it = map.find("a", "b");
  std::cout << it.second->second << "\n";
  std::cout << (map.find("c", "d") == map.end()) << "\n";
  map.erase(it);
  std::cout << (map.find("a", "b") == map.end()) << "\n";
}
```

This is just an initial framework, you'll need to implement any other methods you need.

Comment: you can do some operations on this map that is cool, but this still missed option of iterating over this map. So this is not actually an iterator. Just starting point for it. https://godbolt.org/z/fssr3PWhG

Comment: @MarekR yes, I said it's just a starting point, it covers the operations used by the op in the question

Comment: I looked into your code, and maybe there is still one problem not addressed? Consider we want to find `(a, b)`, then there are actually two scenarios, the first one is that `m[a]` doesn't exist, the second one is that `m[a][b]` doesn't exist. However, seems your code will return `(end(), {})` for the first case, and `(iter, end())` for the next case. So if I want to check if `(a, b)` exists, this check may not function well since it will compare to `end()`, which is always `(end(), {})`. Maybe we can have some fix on that, however, it could be not so natural and prone to error.

Comment: @calvin yes, I'm sure there are bugs, it was written in about 20 minutes

Comment: You don't actually need the pointer to `map`, you can use `{}` for `map->end()`. The `first == map->begin()` check in `operator --` seems out of place. I'd also have `operator*` return a `std::tuple<Level1Key&, Level2Key&, T&>`

Comment: @Caleth fairly sure it is required, do you mean change `first == map->end()` to `first == {}` in the increment operator? I don't think that works https://godbolt.org/z/WsG6aPa5x. `first == map->begin()` could be removed and just undefined behaviour reign instead. Returning `std::pair` of values is more consistent with `std::map`'s `value_type`

Comment: Oh, I missed that you needed the type, not just bare `{}` in comparisons. A nested pair is horrible to use with structured bindings. Either way it should be `reference operator*`, not `value_type`

Answer (score 0):

Not relay thing you ask for, but IMO better approach.

Instead organizing your data into `std::map<Level1Key, std::map<Level2Key, T>>,` you should change your approach and just do: `std::map<std::pair<Level1Key, Level2Key>, T>>`. This way all your problems are solved immediately out of the box. You have to just add some braces when invoking API:

```cpp
template <typename Level1Key, typename Level2Key, typename T>
using TwoLevelMap = std::map<std::pair<Level1Key, Level2Key>, T>;

int main()
{
    TwoLevelMap<std::string, std::string, int> map;
    map.insert_or_assign({"a", "b"}, 1);
    auto it = map.find({"a", "b"});
    std::cout << it->second << "\n";
    std::cout << (map.find({"c", "d"}) == map.end()) << "\n";
    map.erase(it);
    std::cout << (map.find({"a", "b"}) == map.end()) << "\n";
    map.insert_or_assign({"z", "b"}, 4);
    map.insert_or_assign({"z", "a"}, 11);

    for (auto& [kyes, v] : map) {
        std::cout << "k1: " << kyes.first << "  k2: " << kyes.second << "  value = " << v << '\n';
    }
}
```

It is possible you have some requirement where this solution is not a good for your application logic.

https://godbolt.org/z/1K7ovY74x

Comment: I understand we can have a composite key like `(level1, level2)`. However, the real problem I meet is very complicated, it is hard to do so.